# How to build Aseprite from source in ubuntu 20.04? CMake Warning: "No source or binary directory provided"

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-20.04

I was trying to build Aseprite from its source in Ubuntu 20.04 and got stuck while executing cmake.

I followed all the instructions provided in the install.md file.

This is the output I got after executing cmake :

```
CMake Warning:
No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the 
same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will 
become a fatal error in future CMake releases.

CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:16 (cmake_policy):

The OLD behavior for policy CMP0046 will be removed from a future version
of CMake.
```

The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:84 (include):
include could not find load file:

```
/home/shree/aseprite/build/laf/cmake/c_flag_overrides.cmake
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:31 (project)

-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:89 (include):
include could not find load file:

```
/home/shree/aseprite/build/laf/cmake/cxx_flag_overrides.cmake
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:31 (project)

-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:41 (message):
Your Aseprite repository is incomplete, initialize submodules using:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/shree/aseprite/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because the 'laf' folder is empty. You must download this project from Github and put the content inside that folder.

https://github.com/aseprite/laf/tree/8f91e164d1d23a3b0dc751bc0f9185af27dcb2c7